# IF DENTRO DE UM SELECT

Tags: sql

```
    SELECT  @VL_RET_INSS                = SUM(VL_RET_INSS),
            @VL_RET_IRRF                = SUM(VL_RET_IRRF),
      FROM  TABELA WHERE VALOR_TABELA > 0
```

Gostaria de que quando o valor VL_RET_IRRF fosse menor que 10 o campo @VL_RET_IRRF recebesse 0 e quando fosse maior que 10 recebesse como eu fiz hoje, poderiam me ajudar? 
Não sei se deveria usar um if ou qual a melhor forma, obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar CASE WHEN

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @VL_RET_IRRF > 10 THEN 10 ELSE @VL_RET_IRRF END AS Result FROM Tabela
```

No SQL acima verifica se o `@VL_RET_IRRF` é menor que 10, se for mostra 10 senão mostra `@VL_RET_IRRF`

Também é possível utilizar o comando IF dentro do SQL. Falando em SQL Server, nas versão mais novas a partir do SQL Server 2012 tem a função IIF que é uma abreviação da função IF ELSE. Veja um exemplo;

```
SELECT IIF(@VL_RET_IRRF > 10,10,@VL_RET_IRRF) AS Result FROM Tabela
```

Pra entender melhor a função IIF:

```
IIF(Expressão de comparação, resultado se for verdadeiro, resultado se for falso)
```

Answer (score 5):

Simples:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN @VL_RET_IRRF > 10 THEN 10 ELSE @VL_RET_IRRF END AS Result 
FROM Tabela
```

Múltiplos:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN @VL_RET_IRRF >= 10 THEN 10 ELSE 
(CASE WHEN @VL_RET_IRRF >= 20 THEN 20 ELSE 
(CASE WHEN @VL_RET_IRRF >= 30 THEN 30 ELSE @VL_RET_IRRF END) 
END) END) AS Result 
FROM Tabela
```

Documentação: [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)